# Jison ignores one of my rules

Tags: javascript, lexical-analysis, jison

I'm trying to use Jison.

Here's my grammar:

```
var grammar = {
lex:{
    rules:[
        ["\\s+",            ""],
        ["then",            "return 'newline';"],
        ["goto",            "return 'goto';"],
        ["http[^\\s]*",     "return 'url';"],
        ["search",          "return 'search';"],
        ["should_exist",    "return 'exist';"],
        //["#(.)*",           "return 'elementById';"],
        //["$",               "return 'EOF';"]
    ]
},
bnf:{
    lines:[
        ['lines line',          "console.log('big expression is ',$3);  return ['l2',$1, $2];"],
        ['line',                "console.log('expression is ',$1); return ['l1',$1]"],
    ],
    line:[
        ["line newline",        "console.log('line newline', $1); $$ = $1"],
        ["goto url",            "console.log('goto', $2); $$ = {cmd:'goto', url: $2 } "],
        ["elementById exist",   "$$ = {cmd:'assert', elId: $1} "]
    ]
}
};
```

When I try to parse `goto http://www.google.com then goto http://www.bing.com` I only ever get `[ 'l1', { cmd: 'goto', url: 'http://www.google.com' } ]` returned.

I'm expecting to get both goto commands returned.

Any help with me figuring out my grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your code is the premature use of `return`. Using `return` will end the parsing *right there*. So if you use it in a rule that is not meant to terminate parsing, you're in trouble. I like to have one rule which is the entry point of the whole system and whose job is only to call `return` with something sensible.

Here's something that works more like what you want. I've not changed anything to `lex`.

```
    bnf:{
        top: [
            ['lines', "console.log('top is ', $1);  return $1;"]
        ],
        lines:[
            ['lines line',          "console.log('big expression is ', $1);  $$ = ['l2', $1, $2];"],
            ['line',                "console.log('expression is ',$1); $$ = ['l1',$1]"],
        ],
        line:[
            ["line newline",        "console.log('line newline', $1); $$ = $1"],
            ["goto url",            "console.log('goto', $2); $$ = {cmd:'goto', url: $2 } "],
            ["elementById exist",   "$$ = {cmd:'assert', elId: $1} "]
        ]
    }
```

The output I get with the above is:

```
goto http://www.google.com
line newline { cmd: 'goto', url: 'http://www.google.com' }
expression is  { cmd: 'goto', url: 'http://www.google.com' }
goto http://www.bing.com
big expression is  [ 'l1', { cmd: 'goto', url: 'http://www.google.com' } ]
top is  [ 'l2',
  [ 'l1', { cmd: 'goto', url: 'http://www.google.com' } ],
  { cmd: 'goto', url: 'http://www.bing.com' } ]
```

Here's a diff between what you originally had and what I suggest:

```
--- original.js 2014-02-23 08:10:37.605989877 -0500
+++ parser.js   2014-02-23 08:35:06.674952990 -0500
@@ -14,9 +14,12 @@
         ]
     },
     bnf:{
+        top: [
+            ['lines', "console.log('top is ', $1);  return $1;"]
+        ],
         lines:[
-            ['lines line',          "console.log('big expression is ',$3);  return ['l2',$1, $2];"],
-            ['line',                "console.log('expression is ',$1); return ['l1',$1]"],
+            ['lines line',          "console.log('big expression is ', $1);  $$ = ['l2', $1, $2];"],
+            ['line',                "console.log('expression is ',$1); $$ = ['l1',$1]"],
         ],
         line:[
             ["line newline",        "console.log('line newline', $1); $$ = $1"],
```

Answer (score 1):

I would contest your need for a full-fledged parser for this purpose. For example you could do the same thing simply using a [lexer](https://github.com/aaditmshah/lexer) and a handwritten recursive descent parser:

```
var lexer = new Lexer;

lexer.addRule(/\s+/, function () {
    // skip whitespace
});

lexer.addRule(/then|goto|search/, function (lexeme) {
    return lexeme.toUpperCase();
});

lexer.addRule(/https?:\/\/[^\s]+/, function (lexeme) {
    this.yytext = lexeme;
    return "URL";
});

lexer.addRule(/$/, function () {
    return "EOF";
});
```

Now that we have a lexical analyzer we'll create the recursive descent parser:

```
function parse(input) {
    lexer.setInput(input);
    return statement();
}

function statement() {
    var condition = command();
    match("THEN");
    var branch = command();
    match("EOF");

    return {
        condition: condition,
        branch: branch
    };
}

function command() {
    match("GOTO");
    var url = match("URL");

    return {
        command: "GOTO",
        url: url
    };
}

function match(expected) {
    var token = lexer.lex();
    if (token === expected) return lexer.yytext;
    else throw new Error("Unexpected token: " + token);
}
```

Now all you need to do is call `parse`:

```
var output = parse("goto http://www.google.com/ then goto http://www.bing.com/");

alert(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));
```

See the demo for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/r4RH2/1/

Comment: seriously, this was a next-level response. thank you for putting the time into this.